# Is it possible to automatically locate a java RMI registry in the LAN?

Tags: java, registry, client, rmi

I'm not an expert in RMI at all, but I was wondering if there is any way to automatically detect a remote registry in the LAN. Why do I need this? I am programming a multiplayer game and I would like that when you start the game, it looks for an already running server. If the program doesn't find a rmiregistry in the LAN, it starts one itself. If another client starts the game within a LAN, he will find the rmiregistry of the player who already started the game. Is something like that possible? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The Jini Naming and Discovery Service is a (rather large) implementation of exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

At the least, I think you'll have to specify an address and a port range to scan.

This project [rmi registry monitor](http://code.google.com/p/rmiregistrymonitor/) is a small application that is able to monitor a registry(using address and port) a list its contents. It is open source so you can browse the code and learn from it.